# Changing an input fields value in jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

My site searches the Spotify Library and returns a list of results. The idea is that users can click on one of the results and have it added to a playlist which will in turn be posted as part of a form submit. The code below adds the clicked song to a .selected-list container, then adds a hidden input to the DOM with the value of the Spotify song href.

This all works, but each time I click a new song and a new input is added, the href of all the previous added inputs changes too. I know that it's because I am identifying the .track which all the inputs have, but I can't quite figure out how to go about it.

```
$('.spotify-result').click(function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo($('.selected-list'));
        $('.submit-spotify').before('<input type="hidden" id="track_href" class="track" value="" name="track_href" />');
        $('.track').val($('.track-href', this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the idea is to create a new hidden input each time an item is added to the list I suggest doing the following.

```
$('.spotify-result').click(function() {
        var $input = $('<input type="hidden" id="track_href" class="track" value="" name="track_href" />');

        $(this).clone().appendTo($('.selected-list'));
        $('.submit-spotify').before($input);
        $input.val($('.track-href', this).text());
});
```

This creates a jQuery object called `$input` that you can manipulate as if it were an element on the page and when you're ready inject it somewhere on your page. This way it doesn't matter what order it appears in the DOM so if you have to change where it goes on your page you won't have to wrestle with `.prev()` methods.

Comment: This certainly makes sense from a scalability point of view. Thanks. Out of interest, what does the 'this' refer to in this line - $input.val($('.track-href', this).text()); Is it $input?

Comment: @GuerillaRadio `this` inside of an event handler like this should refer to the element the event is fired off of. In this case the element being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your following code:

```
$('.track').val($('.track-href', this).text());
```

for this one:

```
$('.submit-spotify').prev('.track').val($('.track-href', this).text());
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the `.track` class as the selector in the final line of your code (`$('.track').val($('.track-href', this).text());`).  That will update all elements that have a `class="track"`, which, as shown in the prior line of code, every new input will have.

If we could see a sample of your HTML output, it might be a little easier to help you with a solution . . . hard to tell what some of the things are that you are selecting . . .

My best guess right now, though, would be to try combining the last two lines into one and set the value when you create the input:

```
    $('.submit-spotify').before('<input type="hidden" id="track_href" class="track" value="' + $('.track-href', this).text() + '" name="track_href" />');
```

Comment: I've tried this too talemyn and it works perfectly, thanks very much.